# To match a figure in $_GET by PHP

Tags: php, get

**How can you match the following figure in $_GET by PHP?**

I have the following URL

```
<a href="?questions&777">To solve this problem in PHP</a>
```

The number "777" changes for each question. I know that you can get the first parameter by `if(array_key_exists('questions', $_GET) { -- // do this --}`.

However, I am not sure how you can refer to the figure. The same would be something like `[0-9]{1-9}` in Perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
<a href="index.php?do=post&question=How+to+do+this...">How to do this?</a>

$_GET['do']; // = post
$_GET['question']; // = How to do this...
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you change the link to be

```
<a href="?questions=777">
```

Then it's as simple as looking at the value of $_GET['questions']. Otherwise you'll need to use the $_SERVER variable to look at the string url used to call the page.

Answer (score 1):

You separate parameters using **&** and not **?**:

```
<a href="?questions=blah&thenumber=777">To solve this problem in PHP</a>
```

The question mark means the beginning of a query string, after which a bunch of names and values (e.g. somename=somevalue) separated by an ampersand are expected.

Comment: @karim: I do not want to show the `thenumbe=` for the reader. **How can you match only the number when you have the URL such as "questions/777"?**

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would be to to use:

```
<a href="?questions=777">To solve this problem in PHP</a>
```

and then use the value of `$_GET['questions']`